# Open ball in infinite dimensional Banach space is not weakly open

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have to prove that open ball in infinite dimensional Banach space is not weakly open. I have no idea how can I do it. I think that I should reach contradiction with infinite dimensions.

Comment: If it were weakly open, the weak topology and the norm topology would be the same. Can you see why? Can you prove that the weak topology on an infinite-dimensional normed space is strictly weaker than the norm topology?

Comment: Any weak neighborhood of $0$ in an infinite dimensional vector space always contains a subspace of finite codimension (thus of infinite dimension itself). You will agree that the open ball cannot contain non trivial vector subspaces.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more please?